# EPERM Error when running npm create vite@latest

Tags: npm, vite

Here is the error message :

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile '/home/cytech/.npm/_npx/1415fee72ff6294b/node_modules/create-vite/template-vanilla/_gitignore' -> '/data/Documents/vite-project/.gitignore'
    at Object.copyFileSync (node:fs:2902:3)
    at Ne (file:///home/cytech/.npm/_npx/1415fee72ff6294b/node_modules/create-vite/dist/index.mjs:52:325)
    at T (file:///home/cytech/.npm/_npx/1415fee72ff6294b/node_modules/create-vite/dist/index.mjs:49:157)
    at Jr (file:///home/cytech/.npm/_npx/1415fee72ff6294b/node_modules/create-vite/dist/index.mjs:49:242)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -1,
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: '/home/cytech/.npm/_npx/1415fee72ff6294b/node_modules/create-vite/template-vanilla/_gitignore',
  dest: '/data/Documents/vite-project/.gitignore'
}
```

It tried reinstalling node and nvm but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: You dont have privilege may be? Try using sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have valid write permissions to the destination directory and/or the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set up a vite project inside a partition that is shared between Windows and Ubuntu. It means that the partition file system wasn't compatible with changing permissions and that the file could not be copied into that partition.So starting the project outside of that partition fixed the problem.